# I want to change the answer I received from gpt API to JSON format

Tags: python, json

I want to convert the answer I received from gpt prompt to JSON format, but it is not being converted due to request information token usage information, so it is not being output. Please add this to SYSTEM_PROMPT with restrictions related to English word problems. In any situation, I think we need additional promotions because we have to match the given. The openai api key was covered for fear of being released.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from pydantic import BaseModel
import openai
import json

app = FastAPI()

openai.api_key = "key"

SYSTEM_PROMPT = """
You are an AI chat model that creates English word quizzes based on user's input.
Create 5 quizzes with reference to the information below.
1. Answer JSON format.
1-1. { "data" : [ {"quiz" : "quiz question0", "answer" : "O"}, {"quiz" : "quiz question1", "answer" : "O"}, ... ],  }
Quiz Category: English Vocabulary
"""


@app.get("/{request}")
def generate_quiz(request: str):

    user_input = request

    message = []
    print(request)
    message.append({"role": "system", "content": SYSTEM_PROMPT})
    message.append({"role": "user", "content": user_input})

    completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=message,
        temperature=0.1,
    )
    
    quizzes = json.loads(completion.choices[0].message.content)
   
    return {"data": quizzes}




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn

    uvicorn.run(app, host="", port=8080)

#That's how I wrote it like this
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this also helps you in future

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from pydantic import BaseModel
import openai
import json

app = FastAPI()

openai.api_key = "key"

SYSTEM_PROMPT = """
You are an AI chat model that creates English word quizzes based on user's input.
Create 5 quizzes with reference to the information below.
1. Answer JSON format.
1-1. { "data" : [ {"quiz" : "quiz question0", "answer" : "O"}, {"quiz" : "quiz question1", "answer" : "O"}, ... ]... and so on.
"""


@app.get("/{request}")
def generate_quiz(request: str):

    user_input = request

    message = []
    print(request)
    message.append({"role": "system", "content": SYSTEM_PROMPT})
    message.append({"role": "user", "content": 'General Knowledge'})
    message.append({"role": "assistant", "content": '''{"data":[{"quiz":"What is the capital of France?","answer":"Paris"},{"quiz":"Which planet is known as the Red Planet?","answer":"Mars"},{"quiz":"Who wrote the play 'Romeo and Juliet'?","answer":"William Shakespeare"}]}'''})
    message.append({"role": "user", "content": 'Science Trivia'})
    message.append({"role": "assistant", "content": '''{"data":[{"quiz":"What is the chemical symbol for gold?","answer":"Au"},{"quiz":"Which gas do plants absorb from the atmosphere?","answer":"Carbon dioxide"},{"quiz":"What is the process by which plants make their own food using sunlight?","answer":"Photosynthesis"}]}'''})
    message.append({"role": "user", "content": 'History Challenge'})
    message.append({"role": "assistant", "content": '''{"data":[{"quiz":"Who was the first President of the United States?","answer":"George Washington"},{"quiz":"In which year did World War II end?","answer":"1945"},{"quiz":"Which ancient civilization built the pyramids in Egypt?","answer":"Egyptians"}]}'''})
    message.append({"role": "user", "content": user_input})
    
    try:
        completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
            messages=message,
            temperature=0.1,
        )
        
        quizzes = json.loads(completion.choices[0].message.content)
    
        return quizzes
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn

    uvicorn.run(app, host="", port=8080)
```